# Type hints without value assignment in Python

Tags: python, annotations, type-hinting, python-typing

I was under the impression that [`typing`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html) module in Python is mostly for increasing code readability and for code documentation purposes.

After playing around with it and reading about the module, I've managed to confuse myself with it.

Code below works even though those two variables are not initialized (as you would normally initialize them e.g. `a = "test"`).

I've only put a type hint on it and everything seems ok. That is, I did not get a `NameError` as I would get if I just had `a` in my code `NameError: name 'a' is not defined`

Is declaring variables in this manner (with type hints) an OK practice? Why does this work?

```py
from typing import Any

test_var: int
a: Any

print('hi')
```

I expected `test_var: int` to return an error saying that `test_var` is not initiated and that I would have to do something like `test_var: int = 0` (or any value at all). Does this get set to a default value because I added type hint to it?

Comment: Try printing `test_var` and you will get exactly the error you expected :D

Comment: Doesn't matter _where_ you put `print(test_var)`. It will cause the same error.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It is fairly straightforward, when you consider the namespaces involved. This is hinted at by the fact that you get a [`NameError`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html#NameError), when you actually try and do anything with `test_var`, such as passing it to a function (like `print`). It tells you that the *name* you used is not known to the interpreter.

### What does variable assignment do?

What happens, when you assign a value to a variable in the global namespace of a module for the first time, is it gets added to that modules *globals* dictionary with the key being the variable name and the value being, well, its value. You can see this dictionary by calling the built-in [`globals`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#globals) function in that module:

(I will be using [`pprint`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pprint.html) in some of the following examples to make the output easier to read.)

```py
from pprint import pprint

a = 1

pprint(globals())
```

The output looks something like this:

```
{'__annotations__': {},
 ...
 '__name__': '__main__',
 ...
 'a': 1,
 ...}
```

### What does annotation do?

When you look closer at that dictionary, you'll find another interesting key there, namely `__annotations__`. Right now, its value is an empty dictionary. But I bet you can already guess, what will happen, if we annotate our variable with a type:

```py
from pprint import pprint

a: int = 1

pprint(globals())
```

The output:

```
{'__annotations__': {'a': <class 'int'>},
 ...
 'a': 1,
 ...}
```

When we add a type hint to (i.e. *annotate*) a variable, the interpreter adds that name and type to the relevant `__annotations__` dictionary (see [annotation assignment docs](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#annassign)); in this case that of our [module](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#modules). By the way, since the `__annotations__` dictionary is in our global namespace we can access it directly:

```py
a: int = 1

print("a" in globals())        # True
print("a" in __annotations__)  # True
```

### Can you annotate without assigning?

Finally, what happens, if we *just* annotate **without assigning** a value to a variable?

```py
a: int

print("a" in globals())        # False
print("a" in __annotations__)  # True
```

And that is the explanation of why we get an error, if we try and e.g. print out `a` in this example, but otherwise don't get any error. The code merely told the interpreter (and any static type checker) about the annotation, but it assigned no value, thus **not** creating an entry in the global namespace dictionary.

It makes sense, if you think about it: What *should* be set as the value for `a` in that namespace? It has no value (not even `None` or `NotImplemented` or anything like that). To the interpreter the `a: int` line merely meant the creation of an entry in the `__annotations__` of our module, which is perfectly valid.

### Runtime meaning of annotations

I would also like to stress the fact that the annotation is **not meaningless** for the interpreter and thus runtime, as some people often claim. It is admittedly *rarely* used, but as we just saw in the example, you can absolutely work with annotations at runtime. Whether or not this is useful is obviously up to you. Some packages like [Pydantic](https://docs.pydantic.dev) or the standard library's [`dataclasses`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dataclasses.html) actually rely **heavily** on annotations for their purposes.

The value set in the `__annotations__` dictionary in our example *is actually* a reference to the `int` class. So we can absolutely work with it at runtime, if we want to:

```py
a: int

a_type = __annotations__["a"]
print(a_type is int)  # True
print(a_type("2"))    # 2
```

You can play around with this concept in [class namespaces](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#index-50) as well (not just with the module namespace), but I'll leave this as an exercise for the reader.

So to wrap up, for a name to be added to any namespace, it must have a value assigned to it. *Not* assigning a value and just providing an annotation is totally fine to create an entry in that namespace's `__annotations__`.

Answer (score 1):

Python will not initialize a variable automatically, so that variable doesn't get set to anything. `a: int` doesn't actually define or initialize the variable. That happens when you assign a value to it. The typings really only act as hints to the IDE, and have no practical effect without assigning a value during compilation or runtime.

Comment: In this case it may not make that much sense here - for all non-typing intents and purposes this line **doesnt exist** and simple assignment with a value would set the type anyway.  But you can see this mechanism being used to declare instance attribute types under the class body, for attributes that aren’t set in`__init__`.

Comment: @JLPeyret This is absolutely wrong. The line `a: int` very much exists for the interpreter and has **runtime** meaning. It just doesn't create an entry in the namespace dictionary. Just because annotations are _most often_ used only for static type checking purposes does **not** mean they are not useful in other situations. See my answer for details. So annotating **does** have an effect at runtime.

Comment: Ok but existing as annotations is not the same thing as existing as code constructs.  If you cant use the annotation to run code, then its meaning is quite limited outside of typing *and* introspection.  I also remember a podcast by the author of pydantic  that, perhaps earlier, versions of Python, made it *hard* to use annotations *at runtime*.  So… absolutely wrong?  If you say so, though I see your  point.

Comment: @JLPeyret I am sorry, if I came across as overly harsh. I meant to stress explicitly that this statement is just incorrect: _"... for all non-typing intents and purposes this line doesnt exist"_. Same as this by Devin: _"typings [...] have no effect during runtime."_ It is a common misconception today. Yes, annotations were not present in this form in old versions, but that can be said about most things in Python. You can do useful things with them and a lot of modern popular projects _do_. I meant no disrespect.

Comment: I’d also add that the annotations usefulness for introspection is somewhat limited by the fact that are generally not required - your code *mostly* cant *rely* on them having been written out, except say pydantic or dataclasses. But yeah just wrote an answer using annotations recently so I was hasty in my first comment.  No worries I learned a lot here from this post.

Comment: @JLPeyret From the docs: [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#module-typing) “Note The Python runtime does not enforce function and variable type annotations. They can be used by third party tools such as type checkers, IDEs, linters, etc.” I should have specified Python does not throw an error in his code sample because typing is not enforced, and thus does not affect his runtime. Thanks for the comment.