# How to specify return type of variable when function returns multiple types

Tags: python-3.x, python-typing

In Python a function can return multiple types, for example, in the below example `a` is `str`, `b` is `int` and `c` is `List[int]`

```
def test():
    return 'abc', 100, [0, 1, 2]

a, b, c = test()

print(a)
# abc

print(b)
# 100

print(c)
# [0, 1, 2]
```

So the function signature then becomes,

```
def test() -> Tuple[str, int, List[int]]:
```

In this case, how do I specify the types of variables that receive the value?

Hypothetically I should be able to specify it like as shown below, but is not possible.

```
 a: str, b: int, c: List[int] = test()
```

The only viable alternative is as shown below,

```
ret: Tuple(str, int, List[int]) = test()
```

But then I need to unpack the tuple into multiple variable, then we are back to square one, since we can not specify the type for those variables.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about using type hints?

```py
(
    a,  # type: str
    b,  # type: int
    c,  # type: List[int]
) = test()
```

Anyway, the typing should be smart enough to infer the right types even without explicitly specifying them in the final variables.

Answer (score 1):

By properly annotating the return type of the `test` function, the resulting types of the unpacked tuple is unambiguous. As mentioned by @PieCot, any type checker worth its salt should have no trouble inferring the types of `a`, `b`, and `c` correctly. For example, you can pass this to `mypy`:

```py
def test() -> tuple[str, int, list[int]]:
    return 'abc', 100, [0, 1, 2]


if __name__ == "__main__":
    a, b, c = test()
    reveal_locals()
```

The output:

```
Revealed local types are:
    a: builtins.str
    b: builtins.int
    c: builtins.list[builtins.int]
```

I can't think of a situation, where you would need to explicitly annotate those variables, but if you do, syntactically there is no way other than this:

```py
a: str
b: int
c: list[int]
a, b, c = test()
```

An inline annotation for multiple names is not supported.

Using `# type: ...` comments is fine for static type checkers too, but they are ignored by the interpreter, whereas proper type annotations have an actual runtime consequence, namely the additions to the namespace's `__annotations__` dictionary. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74310375/19770795) for more details.