# Python class attribute access fails if attribute has no value

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-descriptors

Earlier today i stumbled upon a behaviour with python classes which i could not fully comprehend.

If we take this piece of code:

```
class A:
    a: str
```

When I test out the attribute access for `a` like so `A.a` or even `A().a`, I get an `AttributeError: type object 'A' has no attribute 'a'`.

On the contrary, if i just give `A.a` a value:

```
class A:
    a: str = 'attribute a'
```

then i can access it with `A.a. # returns "attribute a"`.

I do not fully understand why the first case raised an `AttributeError`.

Comment: All attributes must refer to _something_ so all attributes must always have something assigned to them.

Comment: Only assignments, not annotations, create a variable.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a similar question about annotations in the **global** namespace:

[Type hints without value assignment in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74308012)

The answer I gave there essentially applies to names in a **class** namespace as well with just a few subtle differences.

---

### What does annotation do?

Every user-defined class in Python has its *own* [`__annotations__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#index-48) dictionary.

```py
class A:
    pass

print(A.__annotations__)  # {}
```

When you add a type hint to some name in the class namespace, that name and type are added to the class' `__annotations__`.

```py
class A:
    foo: str

print(A.__annotations__)  # {'foo': <class 'str'>}
```

---

### What does attribute assignment do?

What is different from the global namespace is how **attributes** are created for classes. This is a fairly complex topic having to do with the specific metaclass in play, but *in general* anything you **assign** within the class namespace will end up in that class' `__dict__` upon creation.

```py
from pprint import pprint

class A:
    foo = "spam"

pprint(dict(A.__dict__))
```

```
{'__dict__': <attribute '__dict__' of 'A' objects>,
 ...,
 'foo': 'spam'}
```

In the [Data Model documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#creating-the-class-object) we can find the following explanation:

> When a new class is created by `type.__new__`, the object provided as the namespace parameter is copied to a new ordered mapping and [...] wrapped in a read-only proxy, which becomes the `__dict__` attribute of the class object.

This also includes any method definitions or inner class definitions within the class namespace by the way.

```py
from pprint import pprint

class A:
    foo = "spam"

    def bar(self): ...

    class Inner: ...

pprint(dict(A.__dict__))
```

```
{'Inner': <class '__main__.A.Inner'>,
 ...
 'bar': <function A.bar at 0x...>,
 'foo': 'spam'}
```

---

### How does attribute lookup work?

The **attribute lookup** mechanism is arguably even more complicated, but again *in general* it happens to look for the given name in the class' `__dict__`, then (if it does not find it) in its parent class' `__dict__`, and so on.

To quote from the relevant section of the [Data Model documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#index-46):

> Class attribute references are translated to lookups in this dictionary, e.g., `C.x` is translated to `C.__dict__["x"]` (although there are a number of hooks which allow for other means of locating attributes). [...] Class attribute assignments update the class’s dictionary, never the dictionary of a base class.

During object attribute access the [`__getattribute__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__getattribute__) method is called. This also applies to classes (because they are objects as well).

So the following lines after the class definition are *almost* equivalent:

```py
class A:
    foo = "spam"

print(A.foo)
print(A.__dict__["foo"])
print(A.__getattribute__(A, "foo"))
```

They all print `spam`.

---

### Annotation is independent of assignment

So what happens, when you just provide a type hint in a class namespace, but do not assign anything, is that an entry in its `__annotations__` dictionary is added, but no corresponding key is added to the class' `__dict__`.

```py
class A:
    foo: str

print("foo" in A.__annotations__)  # True
print("foo" in A.__dict__)         # False
```

And since `A` does not have a parent class with a `foo` attribute either, an attempt to access `A.foo` will cause an `AttributeError`. (That is analogous to the `NameError` for an unassigned name in the global namespace.)

The error tells you that there is **literally no value** that can be in any way associated with the name `A.foo`. Not `None` or any other special object! Literally no value.

When you do *both*, i.e. annotate and assign, you add that name to *both* the `__annotations__` and the `__dict__` of the class.

Answer (score 1):

In the first case, you are telling the type checker that there will be an attribute called `a` of type `str`, but you are not setting it.

In the second case, you are actually giving `a` a value

Answer (score 0):

In python, a class' attributes are not defined automatically. When you create the class "A" with attribute "a", you are declaring that there is this new data type, "A", and it will have a value that i will refer to as "a." You have not said what that value is yet.

In the second snippet, you have set a default value of 'attribute a' to A.a, so that if you were to create an instance of A and not define a, it will default to your input.

The first snippet is still valid, however. You would just need to create an instance of the class, like below:

```
#create a class
class A:
    a: str

#define your object, and set its parameters
myExample = A() 
myExample.a = "This is my input"

#printing the parameters of your object
print(myExample.a)
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not declaring a variable, you are just hinting the type of the variable. Python does not create variable at this point. That's why you face error.

```
class A:
    a: str = 'attribute a'
```

Here you are creating an attribute and assigning it a value = 'attribute a'.
So type hinting does not affect the runtime behavior of the code. Actual attribute declaration requires assignment of a value